# How do I draw an EllipticArc (or any other Segment) in a Dynamic Layer?

Tags: arcobjects, c++, dynamic-layer

I am trying to draw an EllipticArc (or any other Segment for that matter) in my Dynamic Layer using the ArcObjects C++ API. For something that seems like it should be straightforward, I am having a very hard time figuring it out. 
So far I have taken these steps:

1. Create the EllipticArc itself. I have confirmed that I have created one and that its geometry is correct.
2. Cast the EllipticArc to a PointCollection so it may be drawn by DynamicDislay.

The problem seems to be that the PointCollection I create contains 0 points, and I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Here is what I have so far:

```
PointCollection4Ptr  finalform(CLSID_Polyline);
IConstructEllipticArcPtr arcCon(CLSID_EllipticArc);

/*Code to construct arc omitted, it was rather lengthy.
  I have confirmed that the arc was correctly constructed 
  and that the object exists*/

IEllipticArcPtr arc = arcCon;   

//Cast to a PointCollection so we can draw it
IPointCollection4Ptr    pointcol = arc;     

finalform->AddPointCollection(pointcol);    

std::cout<<"before pointcount\n";
long pc;
finalform->get_PointCount(&pc);
std::cout<<pc<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"after pointcount\n";

pDynamicDisplay->DrawPolyline(finalform);
```

The code outputs that the pointcount is 0.

Am I completely missing something here? I feel like this should be straightforward, but I have had no luck drawing any Segment on my Dynamic Layer. How is this supposed to be done? Can it be done? Is there a solution for drawing Segments on non-dynamic layers that I will have to use? (I hope not...)

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the EllipticArc class is not an IPointCollection4 (or any type of point collection...). You can see the list of interfaces that an EllipticArc is [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/EllipticArcClass_Class/002m0000000p000000/).

**Walkthrough**

> IConstructEllipticArcPtr arcCon(CLSID_EllipticArc);

This instantiates `arcCon` as an EllipticArc.

> IEllipticArcPtr arc = arcCon;

Casts `arcCon` to an IEllipticArcPtr but `arc` is still an EllipticArc object.

> IPointCollection4Ptr    pointcol = arc;

I bet if you printed out the point count of `pointcol` here you would get 0 since arc can't really be cast to a IPointCollection4.

**Solution**

You should cast your EllipticArc to an ISegment, create a segment collection polyline, and draw the segment collection:

```
ISegmentPtr seg = arcCon;

ISegmentCollectionPtr segCol(CLSID_Polyline);
segCol->AddSegment(seg);

pDynamicDisplay->DrawPolyline(segCol);
```

Not guaranteed to be free of syntax errors, but this is the path you should go down.